# Fastest sim module available?

Tags: gsm

I have used sim900 in my project but it isn't fast, I don't know if it is because it is on 2G or what, I wanna know if I can get something good that can send SMS messages immediately and doesn't take time to send multiple messages, if I switch to something that supports 3g can that solve my problem?

Comment: what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @jsotola I have been trying to make a device that is being used to alert a seleted few people by SMS of a danger in that area, like when someone call on that number, it will automatically reject my call and then send my number through sms to other people that this guy is saying that there is some danger and for more information call this guy, but for that I need to send SMS messages as soon as possible, I have tried it with sim900 and it has reached it limit like it takes a few seconds before it can send the next message.

Comment: And there are a lot of things in GSM like class, speed etc, and I don't know if using 3G or 4G can make any difference to SMS sending speed too, so that is what I am asking here, if using them can make any difference or not.

Comment: `I have been trying to make a device that is being used to alert a seleted few people by SMS of a danger in that area` ... that part of your comment is clear and easy to understand and for some reason the rest of the comment is gibberish .... anyway,  maybe there is a way to send an SMS to multiple numbers with one command

Comment: SMS is a 2G technology, it does not utilised packet switch system in 3G/4G, so if you want to reduce latency, try to uses data network like socket connection.